# Percona-Server-shared my.cnf file conflicts with file from package mysql-community-server-5.5

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, percona, mysql5.5

I'm trying to install Percona Toolkit on the server where there is already `mysql-community-server5.5.52 is running`. 
I require pt-table-checksum and pt-table-snc utility, so I ran:

`yum install percona-toolkit`

I got the following error:

> Transaction Check Error:
>     file /etc/my.cnf from install of Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-server-5.5.54-2.el6.x86_64

My setup is:

- OS: `CentOS release 6.8`
- Mysql: `mysql-community-server-5.5.54-2.el6.x86_64`
- Percona Toolkit: `3.0.2`

Comment: What is your [actual question](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)? This sounds a lot like a) you need to pick which DB to use, and b) like you could solve this step of the issue by simply doing a `mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.community_server_config`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but digitalocean.com has a tutorial on replacing MySQL with Percona.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-fresh-percona-server-or-replace-mysql

Comment: Thanks for the information, but we already have mysql community service installed but I want to install percona toolkit (for using pt-table-sync and pt_table_checksum) without breaking my mysql-server. How can it be done???

Comment: maybe this link can help  (it is a bit old - dated 2013)...  https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/02/21/solving-rpm-installation-conflicts-in-centos-5-and-centos-6/

Answer (score 0):

Install this rpm package and then install Percona Toolkit 3.0.2 after:

MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.54-1.el6.x86_64

```
# rpm -qa|grep -i 'mysql\|percona'
MySQL-client-5.5.54-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-shared-5.5.54-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-server-5.5.54-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.54-1.el6.x86_64
perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
percona-toolkit-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
```